# Print numbers and strings on the Snackbar in java

Tags: java, android, snackbar

I am to make a temperature converter app. I need the result to be displayed in the form of a Snackbar.

- used the Double.parseDouble() to convert the string editName to double.

How do I print it on Snackbar?

My code:

```
    Snackbar.make(view,"Temperature is" +text.getText().toString(),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

[The app: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mgFL.jpg)
PS: I am new and not allowed to use images . I don't have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Snackbar.make(
    view,
    String.format("Temperature is %f", Double.parseDouble(text.getText()),
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
).show();
```